# mysql workbench on centos 6

Tags: centos-6, mysql-workbench

I've installed mysql workbench:

```
sudo yum install mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1el6.x86_64
```

Then I've double-clicked its icon on the desktop, but after splash screen nothing is displayed.
If from terminal I do the following:

```
sudo mysql-workbench
```

it works. What's wrong here? I did the following in usr/bin:

```
sudo chmod a+x mysql-workbench
```

but still cannot execute as non-root user.

Answer (score 1):

**[My SQL Bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64087)**

I needed to **delete** `/home/MyUsername/.mysql/workbench/wb_options.xml` file before starting workbench.